# How can I copy the TXT record into the DNS configuration in portal azure?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, provider, google-cloud-dns

My case like this :

[image]

My website is stored on the `portal azure`. So I need to copy the `TXT` record into the `DNS` configuration in the portal azure

How can I do it?

**Update** :

If I check DNS Zones in portal azure, it's like this :

[image]

Comment: Where is your DNS setup? I mean, where did you buy the domain? And have you changed the nameservers?

Comment: @juunas Seems the DNS setup in the portal azure. Our website uses sitecore and it is stored on the portal azure. I do not know where my company buy the domain. How do I check it?

Comment: @juunas I check here : https://www.whoishostingthis.com/, it like this : https://ibb.co/G3Hd6Ys. So the nameservers is cloudflare

Comment: Is it possible for you to share domain name here?

Comment: @Serhii Rohoza Sorry I can't share the domain. What you want to see? I will screenshot the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation [Verify your domain with a TXT record](https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895?hl=en) first. To verify domain ownership you should add TXT verification record generated by Google to DNS zone of your domain, then wait for a while and run check. To do it you should know which company provides you DNS service.

**To solve your issue** you should follow steps below:

1. Look for DNS servers configured for your domain (NS records):

- via online service [whois.net](https://whois.net/) (if domain data was disclosed);
- via online service [dnschecker.org](https://dnschecker.org/ns-lookup.php);
- via Linux CLI with command:

  ```
  dig NS YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME
  ```

2. Find which company provides you DNS service:

- it could be obvious from step 1;
- via online service [whois.net](https://whois.net/) (if DNS service provided by registrar);
- via online service [RIPE DB](https://apps.db.ripe.net/db-web-ui/query?bflag=false&dflag=false&rflag=true&searchtext=&source=RIPE) after converting DNS server FQDN name to IP.

3. Add TXT record:

- in general it looks like this:

  ```
  Type: TXT
  Name/Host/Alias: @
  Value/Answer/Destination: google-site-verification=VERIFICATION_CODE_GENERATED_BY_GOOGLE
  Time to Live (TTL): 86400 or leave the default
  ```
- for Azure you should follow [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/dns/create-dns-records-for-azure-dns-zones?view=o365-worldwide#add-a-txt-record-for-verification) section "Add a TXT record for verification" and replace `MS=ms XXXXXXXX` with `google-site-verification=CODE_PROVIDED_BY_GOOGLE`;
- for Cloudflare you should follow [documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019093151-Managing-DNS-records-in-Cloudflare).

**UPDATE** Accordingly to your update you use Cloudflare as a DNS service for your domain, because both DNS servers are related to Cloudflare: `eric.ns.cloudflare.com` and `tess.ns.cloudflare.com`. To add TXT record you should follow [documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019093151-Managing-DNS-records-in-Cloudflare). In addition, have a look at the [instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7173990?hl=en) provided by Google.

**UPDATE 2** In case you don't have access to your account at Cloudflare:

1. try to restore access to your account at Cloudflare;
2. collect information about services related to DNS and create DNS zone at Azure;
3. change DNS servers at the [registrar](https://www.webnic.cc/) side to switch from Cloudflare to Azure (double check if you use any CLoudflare services).

[image: whois]

Comment: via online service whois.net, the result like this : https://ibb.co/1dsmsfM. via online service dnschecker.org, the result like this : https://postimg.cc/vx6LrSBC

Comment: I updated my question. I'm actually still confused where I added the TXT record. Did I add it on the portal azure or cloudflare? Now I only have access to the portal azure

Comment: So should it be added via cloudflare? Can it be added via the portal azure? If you see an update from my question. I uploaded a picture. On the portal azure there is dns zones

Comment: Yes, it should be updated at Cloudflare, because both DNS servers are related to Cloudflare: eric.ns.cloudflare.com and tess.ns.cloudglare.com.

Comment: You can migrate you DNS zone from Cloudflare to Azure, but it could be time-consuming and complicated if you use other services at Cloudflare.

Comment: As I can see, there's no DNS zone at Azure. So, it's not possible to make this configuration at Azure at the moment.

Comment: I do not have access to Cloudflare. So I can't add the TXT record

Comment: What do you mean this link : https://www.webnic.cc/? You talk about webnic. Even though my website uses cloudflare

Comment: Accordingly to whois you registered your domain at Webnic (I've added image to my answer). Cloudflare DNS servers were configured at the registrar side for your domain. If you decided to change DNS servers for your domain you should go and change them at the registrar side.

Comment: Do you have access to Webnic? In which way you decided to solve your issue? Is there anything require clarification?

Comment: Thank you for your response. No. Maybe I will add TXT record in cloudflare. I am requesting access cloudflare to my company. I will try your answer if I have access

Comment: Thank you! Please upvote/accept my answer if you found it helpful.